# Google Drive says Resource.dll has W32/FakeAlert.RV.gen!Eldorado

Tags: dll, visual-studio-2013, google-drive-api, virus-scanning

I received a virus warning when trying to download a compressed .net application folder from Google Drive.

I uploaded the file originally and have scanned it locally and it is virus free.

Using ***virustotal.com*** I was able to narrow down the files causing the failure. Both are resource dlls. It is the `Resources.resources.dll` (English and Spanish versions).  However, when I scan the original files prior to publication, all are clean.

Each time, it is *Commtouch* and *F-Prot* that find the virus.

What would cause this and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone interested, Google has created a feature request to allow an admin to permit flagged files for download. This means, if we know it is safe and getting a false positive we can ignore the issue.

It isn't ideal, but at least it allows for this collaboration.